# js regexp to remove certain tag form text string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have some string with html tags.

```
var str = '<a href="www.com">text</a>
<script>
//some code etc
</script>
............... etc
';
```

I need to remove <script>....</script> using regexp with js's replace() function. Could not figure how to do it.

My efforts were:

```
/(<script).(</script>)/m 
/<script.*>([\s\S]*)</script>/m
/(<script)*(</script>)/
/<script*</script>/
```

no success =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
/<script>[\s\S]*<\/script>/
```

If this is for arbitrary HTML, consider using DOM manipulation methods instead.

```
var fauxDocumentFragment = document.createElement("div");

fauxDocumentFragment.innerHTML = str;

var scriptElements = fauxDocumentFragment.getElementsByTagName("script");

while (scriptElements.length) {
    scriptElements[0].parentNode.removeChild(scriptElements[0]);
}
```

If you're lucky enough to only have to support the *newer* browsers, go with...

```
var fauxDocumentFragment = document.createElement("div");

fauxDocumentFragment.innerHTML = str;

[].forEach(fauxDocumentFragment.querySelectorAll("script"), function(script)
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
str.replace(/<script.*?>.*?<\/script>/m, "");
```